# Error loading http://local host:5555/main.js in Angular2

Tags: angular, gulp

I have a running Angular2 application which runs on Angular RC 6 version.
Now i am trying to upgrade it to Angular2.2 version.

However I am getting following error on browser:

> Error loading http://localhost:5554/main.js

Here are my configuration files:

1. `package.json`:

   ```
   {
     "name": "frontend",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "Re-writing the outdated application.",
     "private": true,
     "author": {
       "name": "ashishr",
       "email": "aashish.ab"gmail.com"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "build.dev": "gulp build.dev",
       "build.dev.watch": "gulp build.dev.watch",
       "build.e2e": "gulp build.e2e",
       "build.prod": "gulp build.prod",
       "build.test": "gulp build.test",
       "build.test.watch": "gulp build.test.watch",
       "docs": "npm run gulp -- build.docs && npm run gulp -- serve.docs",
       "e2e": "protractor",
       "e2e.live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
       "gulp": "gulp",
       "karma": "karma",
       "karma.start": "karma start",
       "postinstall": "typings install && gulp check.versions && npm prune",
       "reinstall": "npm cache clean && npm install",
       "serve.coverage": "remap-istanbul -b src/ -i coverage/coverage-final.json -o coverage -t html && npm run gulp -- serve.coverage",
       "serve.dev": "gulp serve.dev",
       "serve.e2e": "gulp serve.e2e",
       "serve.prod": "gulp serve.prod",
       "start": "gulp serve.dev",
       "tasks.list": "gulp --tasks-simple",
       "test": "gulp test",
       "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
       "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "async": "^1.4.2",
       "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
       "chalk": "^1.1.1",
       "connect": "^3.4.1",
       "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.1.0",
       "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
       "del": "^2.2.0",
       "event-stream": "^3.3.2",
       "express": "~4.13.1",
       "extend": "^3.0.0",
       "gulp": "^3.9.0",
       "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
       "gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
       "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
       "gulp-inject": "^1.3.1",
       "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^1.0.0",
       "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
       "gulp-plumber": "~1.0.1",
       "gulp-shell": "~0.4.3",
       "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.5.2",
       "gulp-template": "^3.0.0",
       "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.2",
       "gulp-tslint-stylish": "^1.0.4",
       "gulp-typedoc": "^1.2.1",
       "gulp-typescript": "~2.8.2",
       "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
       "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
       "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
       "jasmine-core": "~2.3.4",
       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
       "karma": "~0.13.21",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
       "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
       "karma-ie-launcher": "^0.2.0",
       "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
       "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.1.1",
       "karma-phantomjs2-launcher": "^0.4.0",
       "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
       "ng2lint": "0.0.6",
       "open": "0.0.5",
       "protractor": "^3.0.0",
       "remap-istanbul": "^0.5.1",
       "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
       "run-sequence": "^1.1.0",
       "semver": "^5.0.3",
       "serve-static": "^1.9.2",
       "slash": "~1.0.0",
       "stream-series": "^0.1.1",
       "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.7",
       "tiny-lr": "^0.2.1",
       "traceur": "^0.0.91",
       "ts-node": "1.7.0",
       "tslint": "^3.3.0",
       "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
       "typescript": "^2.0.3",
       "typings": "^0.6.2",
       "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
       "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
       "yargs": "^3.32.0"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
       "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
       "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
       "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
       "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
       "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
       "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
       "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
       "moment": "^2.12.0",
       "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.3",
       "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
       "systemjs": "~0.19.18",
       "zone.js": "0.6.21"
     }
   }
   ```
2. `main.ts` file:

   ```
   import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
   import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
   import { AppModule } from './app.module';
   if ('<%= ENV %' === 'prod') { enableProdMode(); }
   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
   ```
3. `app.module`:

   ```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { AppComponent }   from './app/components/app.component';

    @NgModule(
    {
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            httpModule
        ],
        declarations: [ AppComponent ],
        bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
   ```

Please help me to migrate it to Angular 2.2 version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error loading http://localhost:5555/main.js in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258781/error-loading-http-localhost5555-main-js-in-angular2)

Comment: yes but due to localhost word in the issue subject, page is not opening in most of the places (i.e. in my office)